# How to add data-title attribute to dynamically added row in jquery datatable?

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatables

I am using Datatable plugin in table. I am adding row dynamically by jQuery:

**Code:**

```
var t = $('#example').DataTable();
 t.row.add( [
    counter +'.1',
    counter +'.2',
    counter +'.3',
    counter +'.4',
    counter +'.5'
] ).draw();
```

Now the issue is I want to make this table responsive, So more specifically I want to set the attribute of individual `<td>` using jquery like

```
<td data-title="counter1"> 
<td data-title="counter2" >
...and so on...
```

Is there any way to set the data-title attribute of individual `<td>` which is added dynamically on a button click to datatable.

Comment: $("td").each(function(index, value){  $(this).attr("data-title", index+1)});

Comment: Thank you very much ..!!! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the `node` container node object for newly added row and then you can iterate on each `<td>` present within it to set the `data-title` as follows:

```
var t = $('#example').DataTable();
var rowNode = t.row.add([
    counter +'.1',
    counter +'.2',
    counter +'.3',
    counter +'.4',
    counter +'.5'
]).draw()
.node(); //grab the container node

//find td present in this row
$( rowNode ).find("td").each(function(index){
    $(this).attr("data-title", "counter"+(index+1));
});
```

Comment: welcome @Lalitkumar.annaldas. You can accept this answer if you want.